# Wget doesn't exit after copying files

Tags: unix, wget

On my Unix server I execute this command to copy all content from folderc via the unix shell.

```
wget -r -nH --accept=ismv,ismc,ism,jpg --cut-dirs=5 --level=0 --directory-prefix="/root/sstest"  -o /root/sstest2.log http://site.com/foldera/folderb/folderc/
```

All the content from folderc is actually copied to /root/sstest .

The `wget` does not exit after copying and take me back to the command prompt.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: This is quite unclear for me : _The wget does not exit after copying and take me back to the command prompt._ Copying output will helps.

Comment: So the wget command actually executes and copys files. It just never goes back to the command prompt ...Its like its hanging... I have to press ctrl +c

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, and I just add single quote to the front and end of the URL.
This step resolved this issue form me.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the HTTP server miscommunicates the length of a response, so that Wget keeps waiting for more data. It could be due to a bug in Wget or in the server (or a software component running on the server) which you don't notice in an interactive web browser.

To debug this, make sure you are running the latest version of Wget. If the problem persists, use the `-d` flag to collect the debug output, and send a report about the misbehavior to Wget developers at `bug-wget@gnu.org`. Be sure to strip the sensitive data, such as passwords or internal host names, from the report before sending it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the problem but I am not sure how to fix it.It seems as if after the files are downloaded wget attempts to download files from every directory in FolderB. I clearly specified folderc so I am not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

I observe a similar problem when downloading files from dropbox with wget:

- the download finishes (file is complete)
- wget (or curl, depending on what I use for download) do not show up in running processes, anymore, after the file is complete
- wget (or curl) do not return to the command prompt
- returning to the command prompt can be "forced" by simply hitting enter, I do not have to actually kill any process to return to the command prompt, it's just kind of stuck before I press enter one more time.

The problem is not wget-specific, it also occurs when I try to download the same file from the same location with curl. The problem does not occur at all if I download the same file from several unix web server, neither with wget, nor with curl.

I have tried using timeout (with a sufficiently long time) to force wget/curl to return to the command prompt, but they even do not return to the command prompt after timeout kills them.